# React Native 0.20 on Android: URL is not valid as a java.net.URI

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I am using axios to get GeoLocation information using Google's api.

```
var request = require('axios');

request.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
  latlng=${this.state.location.lat},${this.state.location.long}
  &language=${this.state.language}&result_type=country|administrative_area_level_1
  &key=${keys.googlemaps}`).then((response)=>{/* ... */})
```

This request is working when running on the iOS simulator but when I send this request in the Android emulator I get the following exception:

```
{
   config: ...,
   data: "not valid as a java.net.URI: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=65.9667,-18.5333&language=en&result_type=country|administrative_area_level_1&key=MY_KEY",
...
}
```

I have read other posts about semicolons in the URL throwing a 'not valid as a java.net.URI' exception on Android but this URL doesn't have any. This problem is also occurring when using other networking API's like fetch.

Has anyone else ran into this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

encodeURI() solved "not valid as a java.net.URI" for me, although I am using fetch.

from: request.get(`.....`)

to: request.get( encodeURI(`.....`) )